# Is this possible to provide command line arguments for TOR Expert Bundle?

Tags: windows, proxy

I've downloaded TOR expert bundle from an archive from [this directory](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/10.5.2/) ([exact download link I used](https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/10.5.2/tor-win32-0.4.5.9.zip)). When I run the `tor.exe`, this is what I get in `cmd`:

```
Jul 21 09:11:11.941 [notice] Tor 0.4.5.9 (git-d0ed04d50e80fe1c) running on Windows 8 [or later] with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1k, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, Libzstd N/A and Unknown N/A as libc.
Jul 21 09:11:11.941 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jul 21 09:11:11.954 [notice] Configuration file "<...>" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Jul 21 09:11:11.956 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to <...>. Is this what you wanted?
Jul 21 09:11:11.956 [warn] Path for GeoIPv6File (<default>) is relative and will resolve to <...>. Is this what you wanted?
Jul 21 09:11:11.957 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 21 09:11:11.958 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 21 09:11:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Jul 21 09:11:11.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Jul 21 09:11:12.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
```

The executable seems to work fine, but I cannot connect to TOR relay due to my country's restrictions. It gets stuck on `5%` forever. I suppose, I could use a proxy server to connect to a relay, yet I don't know which command I should use.

Where can I find a list of TOR startup commands I could use to configure the client?

Since I can see a couple of problems here, for example

```
Jul 21 09:11:11.956 [warn] Path for GeoIPFile (<default>) is relative and will resolve to <...>. Is this what you wanted?
```

since it's actually not what I wanted, because it doesn't specify the correct location by default.

What I mean by commands is, take for example the `Google Chrome` browser (or anything `Chromium`-based). We could use

```
chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile X" --headless --disable-gpu --window-size 322,322
```

to start `Google Chrome` session with such and such profile, run it headless with window size `322` by `322` and so on.

What I'd like to do is basically:

```
tor.exe --proxy "<protocol>://<host>:<port>" --geoipfile-path "<path-to-geoipfile>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `tor.exe --help`, which said to `See man page for options`, where `man` meant short for **manual**, lol. Google helped me out, I've found the link:

https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

I'm using TOR's `stem` for `python`, so what I ended up with is:

```
tor_process = launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd="tor.exe",
    config={
        "HTTPSProxy": "<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"
    }
)
```

You can also use `socks4` and `socks5` proxies, too. `config={"Socks4Proxy": "<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"}` and `config={"Socks5Proxy": "<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>"}`.

Still don't know how to use it from command line, though.